# Lookup the nearest value in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I have a column (A) containing numbers between 0-200. By comparing the value of A against the values of C, I want to pick the nearest cell and thereby return the value of D.

So, if A is 160 I want to get C4/D4 below:

```
  C       D
1 69      20
2 144     30
3 155     60
4 163     70
5 171     100
6 176     120
7 189     140
```

Comment: How do you want to compare A to C? What values do A and C have?

Comment: Ok re-reading the question I think I get it. For a given value you want to find the closest match in the C column.

Comment: Yep. Sorry if that wasn't so clear. So when I found the closest match in the C column, I should be able to pick out the value in the D column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's actually the **closest** value required (and not next highest or lowest) then try this "array formula" in Excel assuming lookup value in A1

`=INDEX(D1:D7,MATCH(MIN(ABS(C1:C7-A1)),ABS(C1:C7-A1),0))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER = if A1 is 160 that returns 70, if A1 is 158 you'll get 60